# click close console window to end a c++ console program is proper way?

Tags: c++, console-application

I have just got this problem for a few days. Before, I've always thought that letting the program exit by returning from main and clicking close the console window is the same way to end the program.

However, I've found that they are different. Since my program opens a camera which is an object. And closing the console windows does not destroy or clean up the object. So the next time I have error to open the camera again

I just need a confirm if this is true?

Then why only until now I can see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing a console window in Windows, kills the running program (or stack of running programs). Unless it has registered a handler for this event, it gets no chance to clean up. If you want solution, register a handler.

Hm, consulting the documentation, wait a few secs…

OK, look up `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! so I should not click [x] in a console program unless I've already taken care of the clean up

Answer (score 1):

Closing a running console application will kill the process, not giving you the chance for any clean up code. I guess you could hook a windows message loop to trap the WM_CLOSE message and do proper cleanup, but at the end of the day, you just shouldn't kill the process.